# Why is ISKCON giving upanayana samskara to shudras and mlecchas when it is contrary to Ramanujacharya's teachings?

Tags: ramanujacharya, shudra, iskcon, mleccha, upanayanam

Why is ISKCON giving upanayana samskara to shudras and mlecchas?

Isn't it against Ramanujacharya's teachings?

In his Brahma sutra (Vedanta sutra) bhashya, Ramanujacharya says ([1:3:36](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48134.htm)) that Shudras are not fit for upanayana.

ISKCON says they follow Ramanujacharya and yet they seem to be going against his teachings.

So on what basis does ISKCON perform the upanayana samskara for shudras and mlecchas?

Comment: Where did you come across ISKCON's claim that they follow Ramanujacharya ?

Comment: The reason given is the lack of sin (presumably of a specific kind), which makes the ceremony pointless. There is no implication of a downside of doing so. Thus making an effort to avoid teaching Śūdra is pointless, so why should Iskon bother?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa, by definition, doing takes effort. avoiding doesn't take effort. going out of the way to do upanayana for non-dwijas seems a bit fishy.

Comment: @ram The effort to explain the concept to people would, in many situations, be more difficult than just doing the extra upanayanas.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa, that's like saying 'it is more difficult to explain the physics/chemistry/biology behind why you should not touch fire, so i'll just keep quiet when you touch it'

Comment: @ram Touching fire has negative consequences. Upanayana for Śūdra does nothing good or bad. It's like trying to burn something without any material to burn.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa - *"Upanayana for Śūdra does nothing good or bad"* - your opinion opposes shastras

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa refer the story of Shambuka, a shudra who tried to become Shiva to become Parvathi's consort. Shudras are, by nature, not inclined to dhyana or spiritual pursuit. That is why they are shudras in the first place.

Comment: @AravindSuresh Don't know a better source, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shambuka has a translation that shows Śūdra not performing austerities is limited to Dvāpara Yuga, with it implied to not be ideal in Treta Yuga. In Kali Yuga it's fine. Also, the entire point of the upanayana makes no sense for Śūdra, because they are not Dvija, making it as if praying for the good health of your child when you have none.

Comment: @ram I'm basing this on the source in the question. It does not say anything bad about  Śūdra. It just points out an upanayana for a Śūdra won't do anything, because Śūdra are not Dvija. It does not imply any negative consequences in any way.

Comment: ISKCON is one of the Gaudiya Vaishnava organisations, and Ramanuja belongs to another Vaishnava lineage/ tradition, ie sampradaya. Thus Iskcon are not followers of Ramanuja. As far as I know in Iskcon they never give initiation (upanayana) to people who are Shudras or mlecchas. So the assumption of the question is wrong and opinion based.

Comment: @brahma-jijnasa sir mleccha means other religion person

Comment: They are doing upanayana to shudras also

Comment: "As far as I know in Iskcon they never give initiation (upanayana) to people who are Shudras or mlecchas." - what exactly do you mean by this? Shudras/Mlecchas by birth or by nature? What do you have to say about [this letter](https://vanisource.org/w/index.php?title=740123_-_Letter_to_Sahadeva_written_from_Honolulu&hl=brahmana%20initiation) of Prabhupada where he says ISKCON shouldn't have any problem initiating disciples who were once Shudras/Mlecchas by birth but now have become Brahmana due to their training? @brahmajijnasa

Comment: @sv. I think Srila Prabhupada (SP) did not believe that people who became the devotees of ISKCON and where given 2nd initiation called as brahmana initiation were born with nature or consciousness of Sudras. SP believed only that there is a possibility for a person who has the brahminical nature or consciousness to be born in a family of Sudras/Mlecchas, but that doesn't mean that the person born like that is really a Sudra/Mleccha. Such a person could be designated as Sudra/Mleccha because of birth, ie because he was born in a family of Sudras/Mlecchas, but not because of his inner nature ...

Comment: @sv. ... which is higher than a nature of a Sudra/Mleccha. If such a person stick to the principles of devotional Vaishnava life under the guidance of a guru, he is eligible to take a brahmanical or 2nd initiation, ie upanayana in due time. And then he shouldn't be designated as Sudra anymore. That's where SP and Gaudiya Vaishnavas differ in opinion from some Hindus who believe that one who was born in a family of Sudras/Mlecchas stays to be a Sudra/Mleccha to the end of his life. In opinion of Gaudiya Vaishnavas such one can be accepted as a brahmana if he is qualified for upanayana.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa OP is clearly talking shudras and mlecchas due to their birth. I don't think he believes in guna-based system of SP or ISKCON where a brahmana can be born into a shudra/mleccha family. So even though ISKCON thinks a 'brahmana' born in shudra/mleccha family is eligible for upanayana, OP still considers such a 'brahmana' to be a shudra/mleccha. I'm simply asking, what you really meant by your earlier statement, "in Iskcon they never give initiation (upanayana) to people who are Shudras or mlecchas" – this is clearly contradicting SP's statements, ISKCON's day to day affairs, etc.

Comment: @sv. Well, if OP thinks like that, like you explained, then I must say he thinks wrong :) You said *this is clearly contradicting SP's statements, ISKCON's day to day affairs, etc.* -- So, you think SP gave initiations to his disciples who were Shudras/Mlecchas? I explained above what was SP's belief on that issue.

Answer (score 6):

As ISKCON's Governing Body Commission (GBC) [clarified recently](https://iskconnews.org/gbc-approves-vaishnavi-diksa-gurus-in-iskcon,7126/) while appointing female [dīkṣā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diksha) gurus, they rely on the teachings of [Swami Prabhupada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._C._Bhaktivedanta_Swami_Prabhupada) and [Chaitanya Mahaprabhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu) and not that of [Ramanujacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanuja):

> **The primary bases for this decision are the expressed desires and instructions** on guru qualifications **of** ISKCON's Founder-acarya His Divine Grace Srila A.C. Bhaktivedanta **Swami Prabhupada**.
>
> ...
>
> **We recognize that some members and friends of ISKCON may object to this resolution based on their own reading of sastra, their own social experiences, or deeply held Vaisnava convictions.**
>
> ...
>
> In the meantime, we humbly request ISKCON devotees to see this resolution in **the light of the inclusiveness of Lord Chaitanya and our previous acaryas**, and as facilitating senior, mature and exemplary followers of Srila Prabhupada in their dedicated service to him and his ISKCON. Please bless them in this new important spiritual responsibility.
>
> > **So one who is spreading krsna-upadesa, simply repeat what is said by Krsna, then you become acarya.** (...) Suppose you have got now ten thousand. We shall expand to hundred thousand. That is required. Then hundred thousand to million, and million to ten million. So there will be no scarcity of acarya, and people will understand Krsna consciousness very easily.
> >
> > ([Lecture on Sri Caitanya-caritamrta, Adi-lila 1.13 – April 6, 1975, Mayapur](https://vedabase.io/en/library/transcripts/750406ccmay/))

As for upanayana or brāhmaṇa initiation performed for "śūdra" and "mleccha" disciples, this is what Prabhupada [has stated](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/24/330/):

> Similarly, a disciple's qualifications must be observed by the spiritual master before he is accepted as a disciple. In our Kṛṣṇa consciousness movement, the requirement is that one must be prepared to give up the four pillars of sinful life — illicit sex, meat-eating, intoxication and gambling. **In Western countries especially, we first observe whether a potential disciple is prepared to follow the regulative principles.** Then he is given the name of a Vaiṣṇava servant and initiated to chant the Hare Kṛṣṇa mahā-mantra, at least sixteen rounds daily. In this way the disciple renders devotional service under the guidance of the spiritual master or his representative for at least six months to a year. **He is then recommended for a second initiation, during which a sacred thread is offered and the disciple is accepted as a bona fide brāhmaṇa.** Śrīla Bhaktisiddhānta Sarasvatī Ṭhākura introduced the system of giving the sacred thread to a bona fide Vaiṣṇava, and we are following in his footsteps.
>
> **The qualifications of a bona fide disciple are described in Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam ([11.10.6](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/10/6/)) as follows**:
>
> *amānya-matsaro dakṣo nirmamo dṛḍha-sauhṛdaḥ* । 
> *asatvaro ’rtha-jijñāsur anasūyur amogha-vāk* ॥ 11.10.6 ॥
>
> The disciple must have the following qualifications. He must give up interest in the material bodily conception. He must give up material lust, anger, greed, illusion, madness and envy. He should be interested only in understanding the science of God, and he should be ready to consider all points in this matter. He should no longer think, “I am this body,” or, “This thing belongs to me.” One must love the spiritual master with unflinching faith, and one must be very steady and fixed. The bona fide disciple should be inquisitive to understand transcendental subject matter. He must not search out faults among good qualities, and he should no longer be interested in material topics. His only interest should be Kṛṣṇa, the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

He states the same in [a letter](https://vanisource.org/w/index.php?title=740123_-_Letter_to_Sahadeva_written_from_Honolulu&hl=brahmana%20initiation) dated January 23, 1974:

> We are criticizing the caste brahmanas for saying that the Americans and Europeans cannot be awarded brahmana initiation, because according to Vedic sastra, anyone who is properly trained up under a bonafide spiritual master, can become twice born.

Comment: chaitanya mahaprabhu followed ramanujacharya

Comment: I appreciate your effort to answer the question asked, but it's a bit unappreciative to write an answer to a question which is about to get closed :)

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud If what you say is true, why did Chaitanya Mahaprabhu found a separate sect/philosophy?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I'm not one of the close-voters and I edited the question to make it a little more objective so the issue can be properly addressed. So I don't see why I cannot answer the question. If I may ask why do you want to the close the question even after the edit? You want it to remain unanswered?

Comment: Even after Q was edited it still claims that ISKCON is giving initiations to Sudras and mlecchas, which is not true and is opinion based. That's why I voted the Q to close.

Comment: If OP makes a wrong claim, it needs to be clarified in an answer. 'Opinion-based' means asking for opinions of users on any subject - in this case he's not seeking opinions, he's simply asserting that ISKCON follows Ramanujacharya & asking a follow up question. @brahmajijnasa

Comment: Well, his follow up question is opinion based because assumption of the question is wrong. In his Q he claims that ISKCON is giving initiations to Sudras and Mlecchas, which is not true. And then he asks why is ISKCON doing that thing, which is absurd because ISKCON is not doing that.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa See Prabhupada's commentary of Srimad Bhagavatam 5.24.17. "The International Society for Krishna Consciousness is trying to turn mlecchas and yavanas into real brahmanas by properly initiating them and stopping them from engaging in meat-eating, intoxication, illicit sex and gambling."

Comment: @MassEnquirer SP believed that one can be designated as mleccha/yavana due to impure conduct or habits such as meat-eating, intoxication (taking alcohol, etc.), ..., but when that person stop engaging in those habits and transforms his life into life of a Krishna's devotee (Krishna's bhakta) following principles of Vaishnava life, he should not be designated as mleccha/yavana anymore. ...

Comment: @MassEnquirer ... SP would never give initiation to people who are living life of a mleccha/yavana. He initiated only those people who transformed their life as I explained. So he did not initiate mlecchas and yavanas. We could only say that he initiated persons who were formerly mlecchas/yavanas. Yes, we could say that, but that doesn't mean that he gave initiation to mlecchas/yavanas! I hope you understand that.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Oh, I was under the assumption that he also initiated those who were completely new to bhakti. If that is not the case, then you are right.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa-at what point the Melchior or yavan ceases to be a morchhali or yavan?  Who has the authority judge that and on what basis? What is the family lineage of such mlechh/yavan? How are they entitled to upanayan a that even Shudra are not entitled to?  One can even be a saint without any upanayan a like Tukaram or Raidas.

Answer (score 0):

In this age of kalliyuga everyone is a born shudra. So, the beautiful part of this age is that so-called shudra and malechha will be ruling the world.

**जन्मना जायते शूद्रः संस्कारात् द्विज उच्यते |
वेद–पाठात् भवेत् विप्रः ब्रह्म जानाती ब्राह्मणः ||**

**Janmana jayate sudrah, samskarat dwij uchchte,**

**Veda pathnat bhavet viprah, brahma janati brahmanah**

Meaning: In Vedic culture by birth everyone is Sudra(lower caste), by accepting Samskara (Purificatory process) one becomes a Dvija(Twice Born), By study of Veda one becomes Vipra, Knower of Brahman is Brahmana. It means a true brahmin has the divine vision, knowledge and powers.

The upnayana samskara is the next birth or revelation to start Brahman Jijnyasa. Lord Srikrishna Chaitanya pioneered this open system and allowed everyone to get God realization.

Ref/source: **skanda purana vol 18 book vi , nagar kanda , chapter 239 verse 31-34**

Comment: Please also quote exact verses if possible